# Git merge commit creates more opportunity for conflicts

Tags: git, merge

I'm trying to understand why I have to do merges multiple times in a long running branch.

Once in a while I merge master back into my branch, resolve conflict and commit. But I realize that this later commit is more modification to a file that may end up creating more merge conflict if the same files are modified in the master branch.

I feel that as long as more modifications to the same file occurs in the master branch I will have to manually edit conflicts even though I'm not making any other changes to said files in my branch.

How do people deal with this?

Comment: You should not have long running branches :)

Comment: Can somebody comment on whether a 2-week branch for a feature, worked on daily is long-running or not?

Comment: It is. I am currently working on project that has almost 2 millions lines of code and our branches lives no longer than 1-2 days

Answer (score 0):

If you have long running branch you can always do

```
git fetch origin
git rebase origin/master
```

to be always on top of the master branch.

---

But as **@David Deutsch** said you do not want to do that if your branch is already pushed to origin.

Nothing will prevent you from merge conflicts. Conflict is conflict. If someone else is working with you on this file this is indication that you have some smell in the project (SRP principle violated). The only way to reduce conflicts is to have only short living branches.

Comment: You don't want to do this if any part of your current branch has already been pushed. Also, this doesn't avoid merge conflicts.

Comment: That is true. Nothing will prevent you from merge conflicts. Conflict is conflict :) The only way is to have only short living branches.

Comment: I don't agree/disagree here, to clarify the question I don't want to avoid dealing with the conflict... I want to avoid dealing with conflict that arises part of the fact that merging the original conflict has to be one more commit into my branch and that itself will have to be re-merged, what difference will I see with rebase here?

Comment: Not only that, but conflicts that arise as part of a merge-commit are actually getting more and more complex and involved even though there war no other changes at all to such files.

Comment: @DavidGrenier I think the issue lays somewhere else. If you and sb else are working together constantly on the same file on long living branches the problem you have seems to be natural. You will not solve it with another approach to branching or using git

Comment: Can I still do a rebase if my branch has been pushed to origin but no one else is doing commit on said branch or will the rebase prevent me from pushing?

Comment: Yes. Not doing rebase and force-with-lease push is more a convention to prevent annoying others. If you are alone in a branch, feel free to do it (it's even a better practice!)

Comment: our server is set up to only accept fast-forward merges, eliminating out-of-control railroad tracks and forcing a rebase locally before pushing, and overall has worked very well on a large-scale commercial software project

Comment: @ScottSosna Can you elaborate, does the server accept only fast-forward merges in the master branch or any branch? Wouldn't this means that rebased branches where 1 user is working on the feature aren't pushed to a remote server?

Comment: Removing this as an answer, rebase does not do anything to address the problem highlighted in the question. Worse the merge done by the rebase seems more dangerous then doing a git merge.

Answer (score 0):

yes, only fast-forwarded merges, whether it's 1 or n users working on a feature, each new "release" has its own branch, and all commits are popped on top of each other